# Registering listener in java/android, a little question

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I wan reading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) about handling UI events. I know java pretty well but still never
had the chance of writing a gui so I don't know much about listeners. Anyway, they use 
a technique I have never came across before, here's what I mean

```
// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
private OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // do something when the button is clicked
  }
};
```

The first line of code confuses me: it looks like a declareation of a new object, but then
its a method? I just don't understand this code and if you can help me understand it I can continue my assignment :)

P.s. two more question: if I have several buttons on the screen, they all share the same onCLick() method? and if so, how do I know which one was clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hi  you can write this way also

public class testActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

And Add this  way...

```
ImageButton Ibutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
Ibutton.setOnClickListener(this);      

ImageButton Ibutton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
Ibutton2.setOnClickListener(this);      


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button_1:
    // action to preform on button 1
        Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, "Button 1 pressed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.button_2:
    // action to preform on button 1
        Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, "Button 2 pressed ",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok that works for me. just courious - do you understand the piece of code i've quoted? it's not clear to mee

Answer (score 1):

As each view is attached with separate listener you each event can recognize that it belongs to which view

use the following approach

**step1** your class should implement OnclickListener eg

```
public class A implements OnClickListener
```

**step2** Add onclicklistener to all buttons

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
button3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**step3** write implementation of onClickMethod

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == button1) {
            //do button1 click action
        } else if (view ==button2) {

            //do button2 click action

        } else if (view == button3) {
//do button3 click action
        }
```